# Pundit is working correctly, but returning a 200 instead of 401 for unauthorized users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I have specs like this:

```
it "should let a user destroy their own picture" do
  expect do
    delete :destroy, { id: p1.id }
    puts "\n\nOK resp\n#{response.status}\n\n\n"
  end.to change { Picture.count }.by(-1)
end

it "should not let a user delete another user's picture" do
  sign_in(user2)
  expect do
    delete :destroy, { id: p1.id }
    puts "\n\nNOT OK resp\n#{response.status}\n\n\n"
  end.to change { Picture.count }.by(0)
end
```

The first one correctly returns a `302` (I redirect after destroy). The second one correctly passes, meaning the user can't destroy, but it returns a `200` status code, instead of the `401` as it should return.

In my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def user_not_authorized
    render file: "public/401.html", status: :unauthorized
  end
  ...
end
```

With or without the `rescue from` line, I still get a `200`. It seems that while `pundit` is correctly catching `true` or `false` in the `authorize(@obj)` method and stopping execution, but it's not raising when it gets `false`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just a detail correction: from looking at the code it should return 401, not 403 as you say.

And a question: Does it render the specified page (and with what status code) when performing this non permitted action on a dev server?

Comment: @JaySchneider Edited the 403 -> 401 issue. One issue was I didn't have a public/401.html file, which I've added now, but that doesn't fix the issue. :user_not_authorized isn't even being called.